# Iterate Feature Selection in my sub model is not recognizing data in my main model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, iterator

I have an iterate feature selection in a sub model; however, when I go to add the input for the iterator, the data that I want to add to it from the main model is not showing as a choice. I have tried closing the windows multiple times, refreshing the models, creating the sub model and dropping it in the main model, etc.

Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

[image]

So with the sub model, when I go to add the Airfields_Border_Clip_Layer file for the Input Features, I cannot find it in the list. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What GIS software/language are you using?

Comment: i am using Arc 10.2.2.

Comment: Without seeing a screen shot  of your master/sub models it sounds like you need to expose the input to the iterator as a parameter?

Comment: I'll get the screen shot on here shortly but you are saying make the input in the main model a model parameter or the input in the sub a model parameter?

Comment: Expose the input to the iterator in your sub-model (right click, make variable from parameter), then make it a parameter. You will then be able to join the FeatureLayer to the sub-model.

Comment: I'll try that. I actually got it to work by running the beginning processes in the model, which created the feature layers, then I was able to select the layers in the sub model. I then cleared out the layers but the sub model was able to remember the layer. Thank you.